# Drag and drop from QTreeView to QListView with file copy in Qt5

Tags: qt, drag-and-drop, qt5.4

I try to have a drag-and-drop from a Treeview (templates directory) to a Listview (project directory). I read that best solution is to implement mimeData() and dropMimeData() from Model. For now, I don't know what to put inside the functions and my test works only for drag.

I set them with as this :

Treeview :

- model = QFileSystemModel (templates path)
- dragEnable = true
- dragDropMode = dragOnly
- defaultDropAction = copyAction

Listview :

- model = QFileSystemModel (project path) with ReadOnly=false
- dragDropMode = dropOnly
- sefaultDropAction = copyAction

Comment: Have you set [acceptDrops](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#acceptDrops-prop) to true?

Comment: Yes, I tried it but item still doesn't want to drop.

Answer (score 0):

If dragging is already working, for dropping you should reimplement the *dragEnterEvent()* and *dropEvent()* event handler functions of the receiving QWidget.

I've done something like this before.

```
void SomeClass::dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent *e)
{
    e->acceptProposedAction();
}

void SomeClass::dropEvent(QDropEvent *e)
{
    //read mimeData() from QDropEvent
}
```

There's a pretty clear example in the docs here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/dnd.html

PD. As I previously mentioned in the comments, don't forget *acceptDrops* set to true.

Answer (score 0):

No need to reimplement events :

setAcceptDrops(true) is enough to make Drag and drop, and the file copy is made automatically.

My first test didn't work but things get better after a clean recompiling.
Thanks for help